# Why is this "not defined"

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js

I am using Express and an API to get some data which I then pass into my view. I can loop through that data and print it from within my EJS template, so I know It's there is some capacity. However when I try to use that data in a chart.js chart (all in the same template file) it says it is "not defined"... Why is this happening?

**App.js:**

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var query = req.query.search;
    endPoint = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/' + query + '/chart/1d';

    request(endPoint, function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            stockData = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(stockData);
            res.render('search.ejs', {stockData : stockData});
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**EJS Template file**

```
<% stockData.forEach(function(minute) { %>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [minute['minute']],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: minute['open'],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<% }) %>
```

**EDIT**
If I change it to be like this it then says that "stockData" is undefined:

```
<% stockData.forEach(function(minute) { %>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: [stockData['open']],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: stockData['open'],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                        ]
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    <% }) %>
```

Comment: What is `undefined`?

Comment: @RaphaMex in the code above `minute` is undefined, and if I take the chart code out of the loop in the template and change the data source on the chart to `stockData` (which is what's being passed in from app.js) then it says `stockData` is undefined.

Comment: `<script>` tag code is run IN the browser, not on the server.  The data you pass into the template renderer is ONLY available on the server.  To make server side data available to `<script>` tags in the browser, you need to define `<script>` tag variables in the script by using the template engine to generate the right Javascript that will contain the data you want to use client-side in the browser.  Note, you will need to "copy" data into the script as you can't just assign an object from the server-side into the script (that will just put a reference that will be dead on the client side).

Comment: @jfriend00 SO I would have to manually do that? Is there anyway make the data being used in the chart come from the server side?

Comment: Using http requests or websockets? Take a minute to see that your server is running in USA, and your client is running in Germany... How would your client know the variable?

Comment: Generating code on the fly is not great. Better create a "static" application that fetches `stockData` from the server via an Ajax request and then updates the UI. That requires two endpoints, one to load the page and one to load the data.

Comment: @RaphaMex http requests. Where do you see USA and Germany?

Comment: @FelixKling Alright thanks, I'll have to do some digging, I'm not really sure how that stuff works.

Comment: You have at least these two choices for your data.  1) Copy the data into Javascript variables that you generate inside your `<script>` tags so that the data is available to the Javascript in the browser. 2) Fetch the data from your server via an Ajax request in your `<script>` tag.  You will have to create a route on your server to supply the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your `stockData` in chart.js is generate by `javascript on browser`. But `stockData` that really hold value that not undefine is generate by `Nodejs` on backend. If you wanna use like this. First, you need to render your `ejs` page, then send an ajax to server, get the response data. Then use that data you just receive to draw your `chart`. Somethings like this:

```
axios.get('/search')
            .then(function (response) {
                let data = response.data;
                new Chart(document.getElementById('line-chart'), {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: [],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [your_response_data_from_nodejs.open],
                            label: 'Blabla',
                            borderColor: '#52D0C4',
                            fill: false
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Blala '
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                throw new error;
            });
```

Comment: does this go in my app.js file or in template?

Comment: Axios is an javascript to send ajax request really nice. Beauty and easy than jquery ajax. For more here https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Not sure if I did this correctly. It doesn't any errors but it also doesn't do anything now: `axios.get('/search')
.then(function (response) {
let data = response.stockData;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
labels: [],
datasets: [{
data: data['open'],
label: 'Stock',
borderColor: '#52D0C4',
fill: false
}
]
},
options: {
title: {
display: true,
text: 'Blala '
}
}
});
})
.catch(function (error) {
throw new error;
});`

Comment: Did you changed your backend code ? You need 2 route. One for render `search.ejs` one for respone json data for you ajax request. I have a nodejs project and draw chart like you do. May be this help backend nodejs https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana/blob/master/routes/admin.js. Script file draw chart https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana/blob/master/public/admin/js/scripts.js 
Hope this helpfull...